# Missing names for matching named groups inside others

Tags: python, regex

Here is a code that uses a named group inside another.

```
import re

text = "def oneFunc(x, y): return 0"

pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
)

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    name = next(k for k, v in m.groupdict().items() if v)
    print((m.group(), m.start(), name))
```

Here is the output I have.

```
('def oneFunc(x, y):', 0, 'NAME_FUNC')
('return', 19, 'OTHERS')
('0', 26, 'OTHERS')
```

The problem I'm meeting is that I have the wrong name `NAME_FUNC` instead of `DEF_FUNC`. Why ?

Can I have also the groups used in the matching text `'def oneFunc(x, y):'` that would be `('oneFunc', 'NAME_FUNC')` in my example ?

### UPDATING FOR A "STUPID" QUESTION

The following code that the method used is not good.

```
import re

text = "def oneFunc(x, y): return 0"

pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
)

print('---', text, sep = "\n")

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    print('---', m.groupdict(), '', sep = "\n")
```

This shows that we have all the informations because we have the following output.

```
---
def oneFunc(x, y): return 0
---
{'NAME_FUNC': 'oneFunc', 'DEF_FUNC': 'def oneFunc(x, y):', 'OTHERS': None}

('def oneFunc(x, y):', 0, 'NAME_FUNC')
---
{'NAME_FUNC': None, 'DEF_FUNC': None, 'OTHERS': 'return'}

('return', 19, 'OTHERS')
---
{'NAME_FUNC': None, 'DEF_FUNC': None, 'OTHERS': '0'}

('0', 26, 'OTHERS')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because order is not guaranteed in dictionary. (Return value of [`MatchObject.groupdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict) is a dictionary)

For example, in the following example, `OTHERS` comes before `NAME_FUNC`.

```
>>> d = {'DEF_FUNC': 'def oneFunc(x, y):',
         'NAME_FUNC': 'oneFunc',
         'OTHERS': None}
>>> d.items()
[('DEF_FUNC', 'def oneFunc(x, y):'), ('OTHERS', None), ('NAME_FUNC', 'oneFunc')]
```

---

Following expressions will give you `NAME_FUNC` when `DEF_FUNC` part matches, `OTHERS` otherwise:

```
>>> d['NAME_FUNC'] if d['DEF_FUNC'] is not None else d['OTHERS']
'oneFunc'
>>> d['NAME_FUNC'] if d['DEF_FUNC'] else d['OTHERS']
'oneFunc'
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> text = "def oneFunc(x, y): return 0"
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(
...     r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
... )
>>>
>>> for m in pattern.finditer(text):
...     d = m.groupdict()
...     key = 'NAME_FUNC' if d['DEF_FUNC'] else 'OTHERS'
...     print('{}: {}'.format(key, d[key]))
...
NAME_FUNC: oneFunc
OTHERS: return
OTHERS: 0
```

Comment: You're totally right, I will update my "stupid" question so as as to show that the method used is not good.